# Is it possible to monitor a channel using Astersik AMI

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 
I would like to debug a channel 
 
I want to track the channel activities 
Like Dialing, Ringing, Call established and Hangup etc 

Is there any cli commands available ???  or any other way to do this 
 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I come from Freeswitch world. I would think that it should. A little search leads to this :

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+CLI

You should be able to see all the events logged on a cli.

Comment: You can use netty client to connect to asterisk AMI with : if (channel.isWritable()) {
            System.out.println("asterisk channel is writable");
            channel.write("Action: Login\r\n");
            channel.write("Username: dusual\r\n");
            channel.write("Secret: ******\r\n");
            channel.write("Events: system,call\r\n\r\n");
            System.out.println("Asterisk Id login time " + channel.getId());
        }